# Soot from factories?

Tags: pollution, electricity-generation

If soot was filtered from power plants, are there any trees or plants that would love to grow in it if mixed in the soil, if it is a sulfur substance?

Could it also be filtered and used in the making of paints or something? Is there any good use for it?

Comment: Recyclethis.co.uk has [a question about recycling household chimney soot](http://www.recyclethis.co.uk/20091023/how-can-i-reuse-or-recycle-soot). The answers (none of them with references) suggest many purposes, but *also* asks what fuel was used. You are also not supplying that information. There are many more sites with info if you google [soot recycle](https://www.google.nl/search?q=soot+recycle)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.

The appearance of soot in the gas stream shows incomplete combustion.  This means insufficient combustion time, or not enough oxygen.

Now, depending on the fuel source this can mean that it is essentially pure carbon  which can be used as a pigment.  Anytime you see black plastic, it's about 1/2 to 2% carbon black.  If the source is oil or coal there is likely be admixture of a real witches brew of partially oxidized hydrocarbons.  I wouldn't want it on anything I grow in quantity.

Fortunately, in minor quantities most everything but the pure carbon can be eaten by some bacteria.  (Generally if there is energy to be gotten out of a chemical reaction, there is a bacteria that will take advantage of it.)

A better solution is to better regulate the fuel/air supply at the source.  Some care has to be done with this, as if the fires run too hot you don't get soot, but you do get NOx (Nitrous oxides) which produce smog and acid rain.

Also:  Coal as a fuel produces fly ash.  Very very fine ash. It comes out as grey dust, but in thick enough quantities can appear black.  This is the stuff that isn't coal in the coal.  Mostly silicon dioxide, calcium oxide, but traces of arsenic, lead, mercury, depending on the source of the coal.

More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_ash